# Popup when writing in insert mode part of a string that has been bound to something else

Tags: neovim, insert-mode, popup

I recently switched from vim to neovim.
I have been struggling with the behaviour of neovim while editing which is at times different from that of vim.

I have the following keybinding

```
vim.keymap.set("i", "[]", "{}<Esc>ha", { noremap = true })
```

Now when I press <kbd>[</kbd> and nothing else, I expect that neovim waits for timeout and the simply write `[` on screen.

However, I get a popup showing keybindings that can be executed (see the image below where the popup is just above lualine).

[image]

I do not want to see it. It just breaks the flow.

I do not know if this is due to a plugin that I installed.

Following is the list of plugins installed using lazy.

```
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath 'data' .. '/lazy/lazy.nvim'
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system {
    'git',
    'clone',
    '--filter=blob:none',
    'https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git',
    '--branch=stable', -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  }
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-- NOTE: Here is where you install your plugins.
--  You can configure plugins using the `config` key.
--
--  You can also configure plugins after the setup call,
--    as they will be available in your neovim runtime.
require('lazy').setup({
  -- NOTE: First, some plugins that don't require any configuration

  -- Git related plugins
  'tpope/vim-fugitive',
  'tpope/vim-rhubarb',

  -- Detect tabstop and shiftwidth automatically
  'tpope/vim-sleuth',

  -- NOTE: This is where your plugins related to LSP can be installed.
  --  The configuration is done below. Search for lspconfig to find it below.
  {
    -- LSP Configuration & Plugins
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    dependencies = {
      -- Automatically install LSPs to stdpath for neovim
      { 'williamboman/mason.nvim', config = true },
      'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',

      -- Useful status updates for LSP
      -- NOTE: `opts = {}` is the same as calling `require('fidget').setup({})`
      { 'j-hui/fidget.nvim', opts = {} },

      -- Additional lua configuration, makes nvim stuff amazing!
      'folke/neodev.nvim',
    },
  },

  {
    -- Autocompletion
    'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp',
    dependencies = {
      {
            "SmiteshP/nvim-navbuddy",
            dependencies = {
                "SmiteshP/nvim-navic",
                "MunifTanjim/nui.nvim"
            },
            opts = { lsp = { auto_attach = true } }
      },
      -- Snippet Engine & its associated nvim-cmp source
      'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip',
      'saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip',

      -- Adds LSP completion capabilities
      'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp',
      'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer',
      'hrsh7th/cmp-path'
      -- Adds a number of user-friendly snippets
      --'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets',
    },
  },

  -- Useful plugin to show you pending keybinds.
  { 'folke/which-key.nvim', opts = {} },
  {
    -- Adds git releated signs to the gutter, as well as utilities for managing changes
    'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim',
    opts = {
      -- See `:help gitsigns.txt`
      signs = {
        add = { text = '+' },
        change = { text = '~' },
        delete = { text = '_' },
        topdelete = { text = '‾' },
        changedelete = { text = '~' },
      },
      on_attach = function(bufnr)
        vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>gp', require('gitsigns').prev_hunk, { buffer = bufnr, desc = '[G]o to [P]revious Hunk' })
        vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>gn', require('gitsigns').next_hunk, { buffer = bufnr, desc = '[G]o to [N]ext Hunk' })
        vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ph', require('gitsigns').preview_hunk, { buffer = bufnr, desc = '[P]review [H]unk' })
      end,
    },
  },

  {
    -- Theme inspired by Atom
    'navarasu/onedark.nvim',
    priority = 1000,
    config = function()
      vim.cmd.colorscheme 'onedark'
    end,
  },

  {
    -- Set lualine as statusline
    'nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim',
    -- See `:help lualine.txt`
    opts = {
      options = {
        icons_enabled = false,
        theme = 'onedark',
        component_separators = '|',
        section_separators = '',
      },
    },
  },

  {
    -- Add indentation guides even on blank lines
    'lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim',
    -- Enable `lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim`
    -- See `:help indent_blankline.txt`
    opts = {
      char = '┊',
      show_trailing_blankline_indent = false,
    },
  },

  -- "gc" to comment visual regions/lines
  { 'numToStr/Comment.nvim', opts = {} },

  -- Fuzzy Finder (files, lsp, etc)
  { 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', branch = '0.1.x', dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' } },

  -- Fuzzy Finder Algorithm which requires local dependencies to be built.
  -- Only load if `make` is available. Make sure you have the system
  -- requirements installed.
  {
    'nvim-telescope/telescope-fzf-native.nvim',
    -- NOTE: If you are having trouble with this installation,
    --       refer to the README for telescope-fzf-native for more instructions.
    build = 'make',
    cond = function()
      return vim.fn.executable 'make' == 1
    end,
  },

  {
    -- Highlight, edit, and navigate code
    'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter',
    dependencies = {
      'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects',
    },
    build = ':TSUpdate',
  },


  'eddyekofo94/gruvbox-flat.nvim',
  'lunarvim/darkplus.nvim',
  'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua',
   dependencies = {
    'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons',
  },
  { 'rose-pine/neovim', name = 'rose-pine' },
  'github/copilot.vim',
  {'akinsho/toggleterm.nvim', version = "*", config = true},
  --'lervag/vimtex',
}, {})
```

Comment: Do you have the problem with a bare version of Neovim (`nvim --clean -u NONE -i NONE`)? I try to reproduce your problem but I don't have the same behavior.

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: Thank you. It was a plugin named 'whichkey' that was behind it.